# puppet master didn't pass agent hostname/fqdn to enc script

Tags: ssl, puppet, nodename

Puppet version: 3.6.2

In order to simplify the management of ssl certificates, our `puppet` agents use the same *certname*, **certname=agent.puppet.com**

When puppet master gets request from agent`(hostname: web00.xxx.com)`, it executes `Enc` script with *certname* as parameter.

```
node_terminus = exec
external_nodes = /home/ocean/puppet/conf/bce_puppet_bns
```

puppet.log:

```
2015-05-06 09:55:34 +0800 Puppet (debug): Executing '/home/ocean/puppet/conf/bce_puppet_bns agent.puppet.com'
```

How do I configure to make puppet master pass agent's real hostname/FQDN to `Enc` script like:

```
/home/ocean/puppet/conf/bce_puppet_bns web00.xxx.com
```

Or how can I get the agent's hostname/FQDN in `Enc` script ?

Comment: Didn't you pose this question a few days ago on the puppet-users group?  Was my answer there in some way unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

Don't use any info other than `$clientcert` passed from the agent.

Don't share certificates among different agents.

There are deeply rooted assumptions in Puppet that each agent node has an individual certificate. You will wreak **havoc** in your infrastructure by trying such stunts.

For example, PuppetDB data is usually grouped by owning agents' `certnames`. This data will become inconsistent quickly with all agents calling themselves the same, but being quite different of course.

Answer (score 0):

ensure puppetmaster says this

```
 [master]
   node_name = facter
```

alter auth.conf so that all the sections have the "agent.puppet.com" cert like this

```
# allow nodes to retrieve their own catalog
path ~ ^/catalog/([^/]+)$
method find
allow $1
allow agent.puppet.com

# allow nodes to retrieve their own node definition
path ~ ^/node/([^/]+)$
method find
allow $1
allow agent.puppet.com

# allow all nodes to access the certificates services
path /certificate_revocation_list/ca
method find
allow *

# allow all nodes to store their own reports
path ~ ^/report/([^/]+)$
method save
allow $1
allow agent.puppet.com
```

That's just puppetmaster <=> client, Felix is right that if you are using puppetdb that would have to be altered too

Comment: Are you certain that *can* be altered? Last time I checked, there was quite a bit of hardcoding around `clientcert`.

Comment: It seems to work for me with only a puppetmaster, no puppetdb or other things.   If it starts to play up I'll have to think up a different way of fixing the AWS reusing ip addresses and using the ip addresses to make hostnames

Comment: In the cloud, (one of) the best way(s) is to use a UUID for CN and a secure autosigning method. I sketched such a setup in Puppet Essentials.

Comment: Yes, the `node_name` config parameter is documented, with the behavior @Vorsprung describes.  Dunno whether it works completely as advertised, and I don't intend to find out.